# C# Reflection: asp.net controls are nulls on master page

Tags: c#-4.0

I call masterpage public methods, from the page, using reflection but, once the methods are invoked, the controls on the masterpage returns null... why is that?

Code in the MasterPage file:

```
public void Add_PageTitle(string title, string titleIcon = null, string titleSmallText = null, string title2 = null)
{

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(titleIcon))
        this.litPageTitleIcon.Text = "<i class=\"" + titleIcon + " position-left\"></i>";

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
        this.litPageTitleText.Text = " <span class=\"text-semibold\">" + title + "</span>" + (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title2) ? " - " + title2 : "");

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(titleSmallText))
        this.litPageTitleSmallText.Text = " <small class=\"display-block\">" + titleSmallText + "</small> ";
}
```

Code in the Page file:

```
Type masterType = this.Page.Master.GetType();
object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(masterType, null);
MethodInfo miAddPageTitle = classInstance.GetType().GetMethod("Add_PageTitle", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
MethodInfo miHeadingElements = classInstance.GetType().GetMethod("Add_Heading_Elements", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

if (this.WorkingServiceRequest != null)
    miAddPageTitle.Invoke(classInstance, new object[] { this.WorkingServiceRequest.QuestionPack.QuestionPackName, ((this.WorkingServiceRequest.ServiceType != null) ? this.WorkingServiceRequest.ServiceType.IconClass : string.Empty), ((this.WorkingServiceRequest.ServiceType != null) ? this.WorkingServiceRequest.ServiceType.Description : this.WorkingServiceRequest.QuestionPack.QuestionPackName), this.WorkingServiceRequest.Name });
else
    miAddPageTitle.Invoke(classInstance, new object[] { questionPack.Name, questionPack.IconClass, questionPack.Description, string.Empty });
```

I can invoke the methods fine in the masterpage but the controls 
e.g.

```
<asp:Literal ID="litPageTitleIcon" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
<asp:Literal ID="litPageTitleText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
<asp:Literal ID="litPageTitleSmallText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

"litPageTitleIcon, litPageTitleText" in the masterpage returns null , which causes an exception ofcause.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are creating a new master page with create instance, which is why none of the controls are available.

try

```
var x = (MyMasterPageType)this.Page.Master;
x.Add_PageTitle(questionPack.Name, questionPack.IconClass, questionPack.Description, string.Empty)
```

Comment: Ok, I was using this approach you just demostrated before ...
But I have like 4 different masterpages ... So I thought I was doing a better way to get rid of if...else statement ...
As... masterpages have same methods

Comment: create an interface, make the masterpages implement said interface, cast x to interface, or use dynamic.

Comment: Would it then see the asp.net controls in the said masterpage that will implement the interface ?

I want to get rid of this

<code>if (this.Page.Master is PageTemplate){
                        var master = (PageTemplate)this.Page.Master;
                    } else if (this.Page.Master is PageTemplate_v2) {
                        PageTemplate_v2 masterv2 = (PageTemplate_v2)this.Page.Master;
                    }</code>

Comment: Ok thanks, i will try that ....
reason is, I dont want to know which masterpage ... I  just want to call the methods of the masterpage .... cause they are the same methods

Comment: by implementing an interface or just casting to dynamic  to rely on duck typing, it would work, just be a bit messy and lack static checking.